# Sceneform ARCore Android studio

Tags: android-studio-3.0, arcore, sceneform

I am developing an AR app that allow you to move a ball by swiping the screen. I am able to detect the swipe but I am unsure how I can move the ball. so I want the ball to move from one position to another based on how long the screen is swipe. so when you swipe the ball is moved like been thrown.

Can any one help me out with this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To move a renderable, you can delete it at the old position and place it at the new one. Here is an example - this is button driven rather than swipe driven, but the movement can be used similarly. The code below works on the currently selected anchorNode - i.e. the user can select different nodes to move.

```js
        //Add a listener for the left button
        FloatingActionButton leftButtom = findViewById(R.id.left_button);
        leftButtom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Move the anchor left
                Log.d(TAG,"Moving anchor left");
                if (currentSelectedAnchorNode != null) {
                    //Get the current Pose and transform it then set a new anchor at the new pose
                    Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
                    Anchor currentAnchor = currentSelectedAnchorNode.getAnchor();
                    Pose oldPose = currentAnchor.getPose();
                    Pose newPose = oldPose.compose(Pose.makeTranslation(-0.05f,0,0));
                    currentSelectedAnchorNode = moveRenderable(currentSelectedAnchorNode, newPose);
                }
            }
        });
```

```js
    private AnchorNode moveRenderable(AnchorNode markAnchorNodeToMove, Pose newPoseToMoveTo) {
        //Move a renderable to a new pose
        if (markAnchorNodeToMove != null) {
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(markAnchorNodeToMove);
            anchorNodeList.remove(markAnchorNodeToMove);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"moveRenderable - markAnchorNode was null");
            return null;
        }
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
        Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
        Anchor markAnchor = session.createAnchor(newPoseToMoveTo.extractTranslation());
        AnchorNode newMarkAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(markAnchor);
        newMarkAnchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
        newMarkAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        anchorNodeList.add(newMarkAnchorNode);

        return newMarkAnchorNode;
    }
```